# Auth check not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.3

I want to store treatments to the database with a user id attached to it. when I run this code it always triggers the else condition even after the user is logged in. I also noticed that the I could return the user Id from GET request but for POST requests, it does not.

My code

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Treatment;
use Auth;

class TreatmentsController extends Controller
{
    //Post request 
    //Add Treatment
    public function add(Request $request){
        if (Auth::check())
          {
            $treatment = new Treatment;
            $treatment->name = $request->treatmentName;
            $treatment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $treatment->company_id = Auth::user()->company->id;
            $treatment->save();
          }else{
            //user not logged in
          }
      }

}
```

Comment: If you do `dd(Auth::user())` before the if, does it return null or the logged in user ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your user logged in ? Auth::user() returns NULL without login. Try this

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Treatment;
    use Auth;

    class TreatmentsController extends Controller
    {
        //Post request 
        //Add Treatment
        public function add(Request $request){
            if (Auth::check())
            {
              $user = Auth::user();
              $treatment = new Treatment;
              $treatment->name = $request->treatmentName;
              $treatment->user_id = $user->id;
              $treatment->company_id = $user->company->id;
              $treatment->save();
            }else{
              //functionality for not logged users
            }
          }

    }
```

Comment: Yes tried this but it seems not taking a user as logged in even after the user is logged in. It was triggering the else condition

Comment: Are you used more than one guard? Try this: `Auth::guard('web')->user()->id`

Comment: Thanks for your response but it still triggers the else condition

Comment: Add `->middleware('auth')` to your route.

Comment: Thanks all who gave their time. Actually, I was sending post request from Axios, Now I am sending post request from blade file and it worked. Now I can access user id, I think if you try to send post request from `Vue` file then it does not let you check `auth`.

Comment: Interesting @Jayprakash Could that have something to do with the api control structure? I'm curious because I'm about to create Vue for my website. I'm planning to use the official package Passport. It could be laravel simply denying api requests without proper identification.

Comment: Yes Dimjitri, before all my routes were stored in api file, so the auth checking was not working then I stored all my routes in laravels default routes file(web) then It all worked, maybe it has to do something with api structure.